# remove js from products grid

Tags: adminhtml, product-grid

I added new action in row at admin grid. It works, link oppening in new window. But when I click on link, checkbox meking (on or off [enter link description here](http://screenshots.collabstar.com/ao/144681362508_kiss_22kb.png)) How can i remove event from row?  How can I make checkbox clickable only when i click on it?
I added action on Associated product in grouped product type.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more ? what even do you want to remove

Comment: have you added action in related products or up-sells or cross-sells grid?

Comment: you have to add row url to edit

 public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
         return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $row->getId()));
    }

Comment: @Qaisar Satti Thanks, I tried it, but checkbox meking (on or off)

Comment: @Abdult Associated product in grouped product type

Comment: @Vishwas Bhatnagar How can I make checkbox clickable only when i click on it?

Comment: What version of Magento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Need to change code in grid.js** (magento\js\mage\adminhtml\grid.js)

**Replace code from**

```
 rowMouseClick : function(event){
    var element = Event.findElement(event, 'table');
    if(this.rowClickCallback){
          try{
              this.rowClickCallback(this, event);
          }
          catch(e){}
      } 
      varienGlobalEvents.fireEvent('gridRowClick', event);
  }
```

**TO**

```
rowMouseClick : function(event){
    var element = Event.findElement(event, 'table');
    if(element.id!='super_product_grid') {
        if(this.rowClickCallback){
            try{
                this.rowClickCallback(this, event);
            }
            catch(e){}
        }   
    }
    varienGlobalEvents.fireEvent('gridRowClick', event);
}
```

Note : Please replace your gird id in code. Currently i have added **"super_product_grid"** in code

Answer (score 0):

In your Grid.php define this method empty

```
public function getRowUrl($row) {
}
```

You may also need to create a custom renderer: http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-renderer-for-a-custom-column-in-magento-grid/

*** EDIT ***

try in the grid class (that overrides a core grid `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid`), and return some fake JavaScript function, like this:

```
public function getRowClickCallback()
{
    return 'fakeJsFunction';
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but checkbox meking (on/off)

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: I tried to create custom renderer, but have the same problem

Comment: Updated answer again. Reference: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/73324/69